# Export DynamicReports to PDF with unicode characters Java

Tags: dynamic-reports

I am newbie in Java and DynamicReports. I am trying to export some data to PDF with DynamicReports using JasperReports. The problem is that my text contains unicode characters that are not in DejaVuSans. I have read DynamicReport documentation about adding fonts (dynamicreports.org/documentation/fonts), but I can not edid none of files mentioned in fonts page. I am using NetBeans and Java Maven project. All files in JasperReportsFont dependency are write-protected.
Is there any option to export with unicode characters? JaspierViewer shows all characters, but after export they are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved my problem:
I have read http://rekowski.info/home/technical/java/embedded-fonts-with-jasperreports-and-maven.xml
Downloaded iReport 5.6.0 and java jdk 1.7... I have read lots of posts and all solutions didn't helped on win 10. So I have changed path to java jdk 1.7 (like [iReport not starting using JRE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902977/ireport-not-starting-using-jre-8)). With iReport created fonts jar, where I used windows font times.ttf. Select PDF Encoding to what you need.In my way I have chosen Cp1257, but I believe that it would works with Identity-H. Export font to jar file. Then I have imported jar file to maven (youtube - How to add JAR file to local Maven repository? : javavids) and added dependency to my POM file. In my java project file I have .setFontName("my font name") to style, that I use in my DynamicReports/Jasperreports report.
I hope you will be able to understand this mess that I have written here :) Asdk if you have any questions about this solution.