# I am not able to open iReport on Windows 10 with JDK 1.8

Tags: ireport

I am not able to open iReport. I want to create a piechart report using Jasper.

```
 # ${HOME} will be replaced by user home directory according to platform
    default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/5.6.0"
    default_mac_userdir="${HOME}/Library/Application Support/${APPNAME}/5.6.0"

    # options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
    # command line switches
    default_options="-J-Xms256m -J-Xmx512m -J-Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000 -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dnetbeans.exception.report.min.level=99999 "
    # for development purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea

    # default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch

    # jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"

    jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"

    # clusters' paths separated by path.separator (semicolon on Windows, colon on Unices)
    #extra_clusters=
```

I have changes in the JDK path also.

Comment: `Unable to open iReport` What is the error / behavior ?

Comment: It just show the splash screen and nothing opens up.

Comment: is it similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902977/ireport-not-starting-using-jre-8) ?

Comment: Yeah It is same. It is working fine now. Thanks.