# iReport not starting after upgrading to 10.13 (high sierra)

Tags: macos, jasper-reports, ireport, macos-high-sierra

After upgrading to the 10.13 osx version (high sierra) iReport fails to start.

The question relates to the [iReport not starting using JRE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902977) issue but is triggered by the osx upgrade, and an osx user is not aware of the cause of the problem.

Comment: @AlexK this is not a duplicate of the answer you are indicating because I had no clue that the issue was caused by the change of the java version. I searched on stackoverflow for a solution to my problem but I did not find any. I added this question to help people looking for a solution to the "osx" problem not the "java 8" problem

Comment: `The fail is caused by the update of the system java version, that now defaults to java 8.` - You wrote that the cause of a problem is Java 8 set as default. The same cause is described at dupe. The same issue can be faced not only at *macOS High Sierra*, I believe. Should we (SO community) create many similar questions for every OS?

Comment: Maybe the SO community should, or already does, ask a similar question for every OS, because the problem I had was that "ireport is not starting on osx" not "ireport is not starting with java 8", and I think this post will help anyone who has the same problem on osx and does not know that it is related to java8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The failure is caused by the updating the Java version, which defaults to Java 8. To solve the issue:

1. Install Java 7.
2. Edit **/Applications/Jaspersoft iReport Designer.app/Contents/Resources/ireport/bin/ireport**
3. Add the following line before the last 'case' statement in the file:
   `jdkhome='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.***/Contents/Home'`
4. Save the file.